# OnItemClick of a list wrong item getting selected?

Tags: java, android, json

> On click of a list I am passing some values from one fragment to the other.When I select say the 0th item I am getting a Toast msg for the correct row but a wrong value is being sent to the other fragment.Also sometimes a null value gets sent.According to my code I think is the problem might not be with the list but with the json data.This is my list view code.

```
 public void showJson(String json){
        final Context billsctx = getActivity();
        ParseBills pb = new ParseBills(json);
        pb.parseJSON();

        BillsCustomList bl = new BillsCustomList((Activity)billsctx,ParseBills.custInfo,ParseBills.invoiceNo,ParseBills.barcode,ParseBills.description,ParseBills.weight,
                ParseBills.rate,ParseBills.makingAmt,ParseBills.net_rate,ParseBills.itemTotal,ParseBills.vat,ParseBills.sum_total,ParseBills.bill_type,ParseBills.date);
        all_listView.setAdapter(bl);
        all_listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,  int position, long id) {

                //displaytext.setText(ParseBills.invoiceNo[position]);
                // Setting Values for next screen
                Object obj = all_listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                int pos = all_listView.getPositionForView(view);

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "This is the object position "+pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                InvoiceNo = String.valueOf(ParseBills.invoiceNo[pos]);
                invoiceDate = ParseBills.date[pos];
                custInfo = ParseBills.custInfo[pos];
                itemVat = ParseBills.vat[pos];
                itemSum = ParseBills.sum_total[pos];
                billType = ParseBills.bill_type[pos];


                Fragment fragment = new View_InvestFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentMg = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTrans = fragmentMg.beginTransaction();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("INVOICENO",InvoiceNo);
                args.putString("INVOICEDATE",invoiceDate);
                args.putString("CUSTINFO",custInfo);
                args.putString("ITEMVAT",itemVat);
                args.putString("ITEMSUM",itemSum);
                args.putString("BILLTYPE",billType);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                fragmentTrans.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment,"TABFRAGMENT1");
                fragmentTrans.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTrans.commit();
            }
        } );
```

> I think that the values within the json objects keep moving.Like the 0th value for one instance will be the 1st value for another instance.This is my json code.

```
public class ParseBills
{
    public static String[] custInfo;
    public static String[] invoiceNo;
    public static String[] barcode;
    public static String[] description;
    public static String[] weight;
    public static String[] rate;
    public static String[] makingAmt;
    public static String[] net_rate;
    public static String[] itemTotal;
    public static String[] vat;
    public static String[] sum_total;
    public static String[] bill_type;
    public static String[] date;


    public static final String JSON_ARRAY ="result";
    public static final String KEY_CUSTINFO ="custInfo";
    public static final String KEY_INVOICENO ="invoiceNo";
    public static final String KEY_BARCODE ="barcode";
    public static final String KEY_DESC ="description";
    public static final String KEY_WEIGHT ="weight";
    public static final String KEY_RATE ="rate";
    public static final String KEY_MAKING ="makingAmt";
    public static final String KEY_NRATE ="net_rate";
    public static final String KEY_TOTAL ="itemTotal";
    public static final String KEY_VAT ="vat";
    public static final String KEY_SUM ="sum_total";
    public static final String KEY_TYPE ="bill_type";
    public static final String KEY_DATE ="date";

    private JSONArray bills = null;

    private String json;

    public ParseBills(String json){
        this.json = json;
    }

    public void parseJSON(){
        JSONObject jsonObject=null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            bills = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

            custInfo = new String[bills.length()];
            invoiceNo = new String[bills.length()];
            barcode = new String[bills.length()];
            description = new String[bills.length()];
            weight = new String[bills.length()];
            rate = new String[bills.length()];
            makingAmt = new String[bills.length()];
            net_rate = new String[bills.length()];
            itemTotal = new String[bills.length()];
            vat = new String[bills.length()];
            sum_total = new String[bills.length()];
            bill_type = new String[bills.length()];
            date = new String[bills.length()];


            for(int i=0;i<bills.length();i++){
                JSONObject jo = bills.getJSONObject(i);
                custInfo[i] = jo.getString(KEY_CUSTINFO);
                invoiceNo[i] = jo.getString(KEY_INVOICENO);
                barcode[i] = jo.getString(KEY_BARCODE);
                description[i] = jo.getString(KEY_DESC);
                weight[i] = jo.getString(KEY_WEIGHT);
                rate[i] = jo.getString(KEY_RATE);
                makingAmt[i] = jo.getString(KEY_MAKING);
                net_rate[i] = jo.getString(KEY_NRATE);
                itemTotal[i] = jo.getString(KEY_TOTAL);
                vat[i] = jo.getString(KEY_VAT);
                sum_total[i] = jo.getString(KEY_SUM);
                bill_type[i] = jo.getString(KEY_TYPE);
                date[i] = jo.getString(KEY_DATE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

> And here is the code for receiving the values in another fragment.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View viewInvest = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_invest, container, false);

        String invNo = getArguments().getString("INVOICENO");
        String invDate = getArguments().getString("INVOICEDATE");
        String custInfo = getArguments().getString("CUSTINFO");
        String inVat = getArguments().getString("ITEMVAT");
        String inSum = getArguments().getString("ITEMSUM");
        String type = getArguments().getString("BILLTYPE");

  try {
            if (invNo == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "This is a wrong value being sent "+invNo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                sendInvoiceNum(invNo);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        tv_invoiceNo = (TextView) viewInvest.findViewById(R.id.tv_invoiceNo);
        tv_invoicedate = (TextView) viewInvest.findViewById(R.id.tv_invDate);
        tv_custInfo = (TextView) viewInvest.findViewById(R.id.tv_invName);
        tv_vat = (TextView) viewInvest.findViewById(R.id.tv_invVat);
        tv_sum = (TextView) viewInvest.findViewById(R.id.tv_invoiceSum);
        inv_listView = (ListView) viewInvest.findViewById(R.id.invest_listView);

        tv_invoiceNo.setText(invNo);
        tv_invoicedate.setText(invDate);
        tv_custInfo.setText(custInfo);
        tv_vat.setText(inVat);
        tv_sum.setText(inSum);

        return viewInvest;
    }
```

> And this is my Volley code for send request

```
  public void sendInvoiceNum(final String invNumber) throws JSONException {
        final Context context = getActivity();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, INVOICE_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //Toast.makeText(context, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        showInvoice(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(KEY_INVOICE, invNumber);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        rq.add(stringRequest);
    }

    public void showInvoice(String json) {
        final Context context = getActivity();
        ParseInvoice pi = new ParseInvoice(json);
        pi.parseInvoice();

        InvoiceDetailsList idl = new InvoiceDetailsList((Activity) context, ParseInvoice.barcode, ParseInvoice.description, ParseInvoice.weight, ParseInvoice.rate, ParseInvoice.makingAmt
                , ParseInvoice.net_rate, ParseInvoice.itemTotal);
        final String[] barcodes = ParseInvoice.barcode;

        // Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(barcodes[0]), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        inv_listView.setAdapter(idl);
    }
```

Comment: Didi you cacth some error? Or can you  show where did you get values in fragment?

Comment: @tinysunlight I am getting the values in showJson and passing them to another fragment where I am setting them to text views

Comment: " int pos = all_listView.getPositionForView(view);" seems to be redundant since you are getting the clicked view and the position of that view from the callback. At "args.putString("INVOICENO",InvoiceNo);" are you sure, you mean to pass the Class?

Comment: @DanielBo I know I just wanted to check so I used it.But I think the main problem is with the json data.Since I am getting toast for the right position.Can you help

Comment: @tinysunlight I have updated the code for receiving the values in another fragment.Do take a look thanks :)

Comment: Try to print  Arguments.getString("INVOICENO") in onItemClick and onCreateView to comfirm where you get error.

Comment: @tinysunlight i already tried that with  tv_invoiceNo.setText(invNo); but on click wrong invoiceNo gets selected also I am sending this invoiceNo to my server.So sometimes it gets the correct number and sometimes it sends null.

Comment: (AdapterView<?> parent, View view,  int position, long id) @Mekkan08 Try  use this position.Or more simplely , just add onCLickListener in getVIew of adapter.

Comment: @tinysunlight can you give an example where exactly should i call getView?

Comment: Did you have getview() in BillsCustomList?

Comment: @tinysunlight No I haven't its there in my showJson method 4th line

Comment: Show me your BillsCustomList .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97576/discussion-between-anup-and-tiny-sunlight).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this statement for retrieving the position of the view item when clicked:

```
int pos = all_listView.getPositionForView(view);
```

Just use the OnItemClick() generated variable "int position" to retrieve the position of the on clicked view item.

Comment: I already tried that it did not work.The problem is with the json data I think.Please check the updated question

Comment: Try to debug it just before the try and catch statement  in the "parseJson" method and see if the debugger goes through the try statement every time you clicked the view item.

Comment: I just debugged it and it went through the try catch. but I had selected the first value and the 2nd one got selected

Comment: Try to "[pos-1]" for where there is a position in the "OnItemClick" method. I think this will fix it.

Comment: It did not work it gave me a Exception  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8; index=-1

Comment: did you tried using pos value to getItem from position??

Comment: I think you should add the position of the OnItemClick to be sent to the respective class to access the right JSON data row.                                                                                                                'Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putString("ITEMPOSITION",pos);'